# Enabling Headset only setting in Android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin Android Application in Visual Studio . 
Problem is I want to enable app only when headset is plugged in .
Is there any settings , properties , code that can achieve this.

Any push in right direction is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Comment: You could add a broadcast receiver for Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG and listen for when the headset is plugged.  I have no idea how this would be done in Xamarin.